# Different access level for different authentication flows in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm developing an app that users can access through both passwordless authentication and username/password authentication, but I want to limit the user access when they use passwordless sign in and give full access when they sign in using username/password.

A use case would be: A user signing in using passwordless auth flow would have limited access to resources. When user requests for specific resources, or want to modify resources, passwordless session shouldn't allow and the user should sign in with username and password.

Is there a way to do this on Cognito without implementing a whole protocol?

**Some project information**

- Front-end: Angular + AWS Amplify
- Back-end: API Gateway + Lambda
- User authentication: AWS Cognito (+ passwordless CUSTOM_AUTH flow)